# javascript animate textbox entry

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, tag-cloud

I need to implement the following, I have a input box and a submit button and a square div/canvas element below the input box. A user enters a word and clicks on the submit button the following needs to happen

1. The text entered must move over (animate) to the canvas/div at a random location
2. The text should not overlap with any other text .

What is the best way to implement this in Javascript ? . Any examples or libraries out there that makes this easy to implement?. Can I make use of any tag cloud libraries to do this ?

Any pointers appreciated.
Thanks.